# How can I implement in TYPO 3 server side validation?

Tags: validation, typo3, server-side

I am using TYPO 3 version 6.2.14. In this version I am using Formhandler Plugin to generate a contact form. I have implemented custom code of Google 
reCAPTCHA V2 Explicitly render. Now reCAPTCHA code is generated. But it is not performing server side validation. I have also created php file for serverside validation inside fileadmin/templates/fromhandler/serversidevalidation.php

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
      {
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
       }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        echo $responseKeys;
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the bot out</h2>';
        } else {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting </h2>';
        }
```

But this simple php file is not including in TypoScript. How can I implement server side validation with formhandler extension. I do not want to use extension because of compatibility issue. Can someone guide me?

Comment: Did you read http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/validators/ ?

Comment: Yes I have read it but I did not get it. How can I implement my custom code for server side validation with formhandler?

Comment: @rupali you really should upgrade to at least typo3 8.x or better 9.x. Versions 7 and below are  extremely outdated.
There are also no  additional security aptches anymore.
Back  to your question:
Since version 8 typo3 provides a different way for formhandling with its own core extension. And for this core extension there are good packages for extending forms with reCAPTCHA